# How to extract the required protocol from event log file of honeypot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging, honeypot

I tried multiple ways as per my code knowledge. But not able to extract the required protocols **(HTTP, MODBUS, SNMP, FTP, Bacnet)**.

*Header*: **timestamp, IP, IP Country, Request**

> `Input Raw`

```
2019-08-27 12:11:08,078 TFTP Serving File System at /data/tftp/ in vfs. TFTP data_fs sub directory: /tftp
2019-08-27 12:11:08,081 Found and enabled tftp protocol.
2019-08-27 12:11:08,081 No proxy template found. Service will remain unconfigured/stopped.
2019-08-27 12:11:08,082 Modbus server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 5020)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,083 S7Comm server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 10201)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,083 HTTP server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 8800)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,453 SNMP server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 16100)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,455 Bacnet server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 47808)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,456 IPMI server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 6230)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,456 handle server PID [    1] running on ('0.0.0.0', 44818)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,457 handle server PID [    1] responding to external done/disable signal in object 140147125794088
2019-08-27 12:11:08,458 FTP server started on: ('0.0.0.0', 2121)
2019-08-27 12:11:08,458 Starting TFTP server at ('0.0.0.0', 6969)
2019-08-27 12:12:36,979 New http session from 202.3.77.166 (ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5)
2019-08-27 12:12:36,981 HTTP/1.1 GET request from ('202.3.77.166', 34142): ('/', [('Host', '67.207.87.192'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', '1'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8')], None). ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:12:36,981 HTTP/1.1 response to ('202.3.77.166', 34142): 302. ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:12:37,553 HTTP/1.1 GET request from ('202.3.77.166', 34142): ('/index.html', [('Host', '67.207.87.192'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', '1'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8')], None). ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:12:37,553 HTTP/1.1 response to ('202.3.77.166', 34142): 200. ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:12:38,760 HTTP/1.1 GET request from ('202.3.77.166', 34142): ('/favicon.ico', [('Host', '67.207.87.192'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'), ('Accept', 'image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8'), ('Referer', 'http://67.207.87.192/index.html'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8'), ('Cookie', 'path=/')], None). ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:12:38,761 HTTP/1.1 response to ('202.3.77.166', 34142): 404. ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:13:08,778 Session timed out: ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5
2019-08-27 12:14:17,470 New http session from 165.16.37.187 (d39c9889-d4ab-41f2-b4c4-6d16ce34c830)
2019-08-27 12:14:17,471 HTTP/1.1 GET request from ('165.16.37.187', 56987): ('/', [('Host', '67.207.87.192:80'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'), ('Content-Length', '0')], b''). d39c9889-d4ab-41f2-b4c4-6d16ce34c830
2019-08-27 12:14:17,471 HTTP/1.1 response to ('165.16.37.187', 56987): 302. d39c9889-d4ab-41f2-b4c4-6d16ce34c830
2019-08-27 12:14:47,488 Session timed out: d39c9889-d4ab-41f2-b4c4-6d16ce34c830
2019-08-27 12:15:51,814 New modbus session from 202.3.77.166 (b6f3d1ea-dd32-452f-9dab-ab996dfeca5a)
2019-08-27 12:15:51,814 New Modbus connection from 202.3.77.166:39755. (b6f3d1ea-dd32-452f-9dab-ab996dfeca5a)
2019-08-27 12:15:51,816 Exception caught: Modbus Error: Exception code = 2. (A proper response will be sent to the peer)
2019-08-27 12:15:51,818 Modbus traffic from 202.3.77.166: {'request': b'00010000004f0110000000244861626364656667685aee12a9881234edccffff56781234b85241b2b852c1b241112152ffffffffbeefdead56781234beefdea
```

I build the code. But the code have too much bug or I used very wrong coding technique. Please help me. It will improve my way of understanding code.

> `Code:`

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

http=[]
time=[]


def reader(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line_split=line.split(" ")
            Timestamp=line_split[0:2]
            Timestamp=str(Timestamp[0])+" "+str(Timestamp[1])
            Timestamp=Timestamp.split(",")[0]
            main_line=line_split[2:]
            #time.append(Timestamp)  
            print(main_line[1])   
            

            if (
               main_line[0]=="HTTP/1.1" or main_line[0]=="Modbus" or main_line[0]=="Modbus" or main_line[0]=="Bacnet" and
               main_line[1]=="http" or main_line[1]=="modbus" or main_line[1]=="Bacnet" or main_line[1]=="ftp"
            
                 ):   
               http.append(Timestamp)
               http.append(main_line)
               print(main_line,"====>", Timestamp)
               continue
            
            database = ({'Timestamp':http[0], 'Request':http})
            dataframe = pd.DataFrame(database)
            print(dataframe.head())
            dataframe.to_csv('task_raw1.csv', index=False)
  
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    reader("/content/drive/MyDrive/task2.log")
```

> `Output:`

Timestamp,Request

```
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 11:58:07
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Conpot', 'modbus', 'initialized\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 11:58:07
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Conpot', 'Bacnet', 'initialized', 'using', 'the', '/home/conpot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conpot-0.6.0-py3.6.egg/conpot/templates/default/bacnet/bacnet.xml', 'template.\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 11:58:07
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Modbus', 'server', 'started', 'on:', ""('0.0.0.0',"", '5020)\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:05:46
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Conpot', 'modbus', 'initialized\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:05:46
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Conpot', 'Bacnet', 'initialized', 'using', 'the', '/home/conpot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conpot-0.6.0-py3.6.egg/conpot/templates/default/bacnet/bacnet.xml', 'template.\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:05:46
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Modbus', 'server', 'started', 'on:', ""('0.0.0.0',"", '5020)\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:11:08
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Conpot', 'modbus', 'initialized\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:11:08
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Conpot', 'Bacnet', 'initialized', 'using', 'the', '/home/conpot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conpot-0.6.0-py3.6.egg/conpot/templates/default/bacnet/bacnet.xml', 'template.\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:11:08
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['Modbus', 'server', 'started', 'on:', ""('0.0.0.0',"", '5020)\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:12:36
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['HTTP/1.1', 'GET', 'request', 'from', ""('202.3.77.166',"", '34142):', ""('/',"", ""[('Host',"", ""'67.207.87.192'),"", ""('Connection',"", ""'keep-alive'),"", ""('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',"", ""'1'),"", ""('User-Agent',"", ""'Mozilla/5.0"", '(X11;', 'Linux', 'x86_64)', 'AppleWebKit/537.36', '(KHTML,', 'like', 'Gecko)', 'Chrome/76.0.3809.132', ""Safari/537.36'),"", ""('Accept',"", ""'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'),"", ""('Accept-Encoding',"", ""'gzip,"", ""deflate'),"", ""('Accept-Language',"", ""'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8')],"", 'None).', 'ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:12:36
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['HTTP/1.1', 'response', 'to', ""('202.3.77.166',"", '34142):', '302.', 'ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:12:37
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['HTTP/1.1', 'GET', 'request', 'from', ""('202.3.77.166',"", '34142):', ""('/index.html',"", ""[('Host',"", ""'67.207.87.192'),"", ""('Connection',"", ""'keep-alive'),"", ""('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',"", ""'1'),"", ""('User-Agent',"", ""'Mozilla/5.0"", '(X11;', 'Linux', 'x86_64)', 'AppleWebKit/537.36', '(KHTML,', 'like', 'Gecko)', 'Chrome/76.0.3809.132', ""Safari/537.36'),"", ""('Accept',"", ""'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'),"", ""('Accept-Encoding',"", ""'gzip,"", ""deflate'),"", ""('Accept-Language',"", ""'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8')],"", 'None).', 'ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5\n']"
2019-08-27 11:58:07,2019-08-27 12:12:37
2019-08-27 11:58:07,"['HTTP/1.1', 'response', 'to', ""('202.3.77.166',"", '34142):', '200.', 'ca5a29c6-e107-4b18-99c1-08338aabfbc5\n']"
```

> `Required Output`

```
Timestamp, IP, IP Location, Request

2019-08-27 11:58:07, 202.3.77.166, India, HTTP

2019-08-27 11:58:07, 172.3.77.166, US, MODBUS

2019-08-27 11:58:07, 202.3.77.168, India, HTTP

2019-08-27 11:58:07, 172.13.77.198, India, HTTP
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the output you get, and some specifics about why that's not what you want. From a first glance at your Pastebin file and code, I suspect that after splitting on whitespace (passing " " is similar to not passing any parameter to `.split()`), you should also split on `://`, inside a nested loop - since protocols are often identified as "http://", "tar://", etc. It would also help to shrink the input & output data to just a handful of lines - one for each type of entry you get, rather than testing against the full log.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yvbB4AQ12-32DAuaJiSH97XfTmLlU_bJ#scrollTo=pVrkLtXQYXXS this is my colab ipynb book with output.

Comment: This is the CSV Output of code running through task.log file. https://pastebin.com/xp8VKeE8

Comment: Please update the question to include code, input, and output directly - and just a few lines of input and out. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help. Please do not add Pastebin or other links with your code. Please state explicitly what you dislike about the output you get.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with minimal lines of input and output.  I also removed the paste bin links.

Comment: The string "Conpot" does not appear to be in either your input file or your code, but it is in your sample output. Are you sure that output corresponds to the input you provided? Also, S7COMM and SNMP are both protocols mentioned in your input file, but they're not in your output. How / why are you filtering them?

Comment: I was just trying to get some required data only like FTP, SNMP, HTTP,  BACNET AND MODBUS. The input is different and output is different because i run the code on big log file. If you will say, I will run the code on that input file.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned before, we need 1) your code, 2) your input, 3) your output, 4) your desired output and explicit differences from what you actually got, 5) a _minimal_  _reproducible_ example, 6) everything explicit.